# rotate one of the 2 canvas objects placed in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, canvas

I'm developing web app using canvas and I made three. `canvas, canvas_panorama` and `canvas_image`.
First one is something like main canvas, conteiner for the others. `canvas_panorama` is a background for `canvas_image`.

After canvas is right clicked, I'm computing angle to rotate `canvas_image`:

```
function getAngle( e, pw /*canvas*/ ){
      var offset = pw.offset();
      var center_x = (offset.left) + ($(pw).width() / 2);
      var center_y = (offset.top) + ($(pw).height() / 2);
      var mouse_x = e.pageX;
      var mouse_y = e.pageY;
      var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
      angle = radians;
}
```

After I have an angle I'm trying to rotate `canvas_image` like this:

```
function redraw(){
    var p1 = ctx.transformedPoint(0,0);
    var p2 = ctx.transformedPoint(canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.clearRect( p1.x, p1.y, p2.x-p1.x, p2.y-p1.y );

    canvas_image_ctx.drawImage(image_img, 0, 0, 150, 150);

    canvas_panorama_ctx.drawImage(panorama_img, 0, 0, 600, 300);
    canvas_panorama_ctx.drawImage(canvas_image, 20, 20);

    // rotate panorama_img around its center
    // x = x + 0.5 * width
    // y = y + 0.5 * height
    canvas_panorama_ctx.translate(95, 95);
    canvas_panorama_ctx.rotate(angle);
    // translate to back
    canvas_panorama_ctx.translate(-95, -95);

    ctx.drawImage(canvas_panorama, 0, 0);
 }
```

But this rotates both `canvas_image` and `canvas_panorama`. It should only rotate `canvas_image`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bimbochobot/nenb32f6/6/) to show you my problem

Comment: I'm trying to rotate canvas with lady inside with right mouse button. I tried to use canvas_image_ctx.rotate( angle ) but this rotated only image in canvas_image and not all canvas_image. See: https://jsfiddle.net/bimbochobot/nenb32f6/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing yourself with this idea of multiple canvases.

Once in the `drawImage()` method, every of your canvases are just images, and could be just one or even just plain shapes.

Transformation methods do apply to the canvas' context's matrix, and will have effect only if you do some drawing operations when they are set.

Note : To reset your context matrix, you can either use `save();` and `restore()` methods which will also save all other properties of your context, so if you only need to reset the transform, then it's preferred to simply reset the transformation matrix to its default : `ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)`.

Here is a simplified example to make things clearer :

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// a single shape, with the border of the context matrix
var drawRect = function(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(10, 10, 50, 20);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.stroke();
};

// set the color of our shapes
var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,70,0);
gradient.addColorStop(0,"green");
gradient.addColorStop(1,"yellow");
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;

// here comes the actual drawings

//we don't have modified the transform matrix yet
ctx.strokeStyle  = "green";
drawRect();

// here we translate of 100px then we do rotate the context of 45deg
ctx.translate(100, 0)
ctx.rotate(Math.PI/4)
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
drawRect();

// reset the matrix
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);

// here we move of 150px to the right and 25px to the bottom
ctx.translate(150, 25)
ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
drawRect();

// reset the matrix
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
```

In your code, you are setting the transformations on the canvas that does represent your image, and you do draw every of your canvases at each call.

What you want instead, is to set the transformation on the main canvas only, and draw the non-transformed image :

```js
var main_ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img_canvas = canvas.cloneNode();

var bg_canvas = canvas.cloneNode();

var angle = 0;

// draw on the main canvas, and only on the main canvas
var drawToMain = function(){
  // first clear the canvas
  main_ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // draw the background image
  main_ctx.drawImage(bg_canvas, 0,0);
  // do the transforms
  main_ctx.translate(img_canvas.width/2, img_canvas.height/2);
  main_ctx.rotate(angle);
  main_ctx.translate(-img_canvas.width/2, -img_canvas.height/2);
  // draw the img with the transforms applied
  main_ctx.drawImage(img_canvas, 0,0);
  // reset the transforms
  main_ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  };

// I changed the event to a simple onclick
canvas.onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    angle+=Math.PI/8;
    drawToMain();
  }


// a dirty image loader
var init = function(){
  var img = (this.src.indexOf('lena')>0);
  var this_canvas = img ? img_canvas : bg_canvas;
  this_canvas.width = this.width;
  this_canvas.height = this.height;
  this_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0,0);
  if(!--toLoad){
      drawToMain();
    }
  };

var toLoad = 2;
var img = new Image();
img.onload = init;
img.src = "http://pgmagick.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_images/lena_scale.jpg";

var bg = new Image();
bg.onload = init;
bg.src = 'http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggradHDrgba.png';
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: @Kalido your solution looks great but I'm kind of lost there, what exactly does canvas.cloneNode(); ? Does it create another canvas? I need to store this 'lena' image and backgroud image in separeted canvases to make them draggable and zoomable later. First I want to move image (lena) just in area of panorama and second I want to move panorama and image has to be on the same position in panorama. Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/bimbochobot/9z40gepr/

Comment: yes `cloneNode` is just to avoid calling `document.createElement('canvas')` but does return exactly the same. For your dragging objects, you don't need different canvases, you only need to create some objects (`{}`) where you will store their x,y position, their angle, and their scale, and then just draw the images at wanted position, rotation and scale. But that's an other question, that might already have been asked in here. If you can't find a solution, then ask a new question.

Comment: Got it. Thank you, this was perfect help!